# Outlook on Android (11) image size exploding

Tags: android, html, outlook, html-email

Templates that had previously worked are now exhibiting very odd behavior on Outlook for Android (11).  Our logo image is strangely HUGE and wrapped in all sorts of weird ways.  The actual file is 8bit, PNG, 300x79.  Outlook desktop and OWA appear fine, as does iOS mail, Gmail etc.  Our image code is this:

```
<table width="100%" role="presentation" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="max-width:640px;background:#ffffff !important">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding-top:5px;">
    <!--[if mso]>
      <table width="50%"><tr><td>
        <img width="280" src="cid:logo" style="text-align: right; width: 280px; border: 0; text-decoration:none; vertical-align: baseline;" border="0" />
      </td></tr></table>
      <div style="display:none;">
    <![endif]-->
      <img style="max-width:300px !important;height:auto;" src="cid:logo" border="0" />
    <!--[if mso]>
      </div>
    <![endif]-->
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What we're seeing here is actually a portion of the letter "A".  The orange is a 10px high orange bar that runs across the top of our emails.

I've cleared all data and cache from my Outlook mobile.  No difference.  Before I go any crazier, am I missing something here in this code?  What's even weirded is if I change the template to just text and do not include the image (inline displayed using contentid) is Outlook on Android still shows the image as below.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can't recreate the problem, but, not sure why there's no width on the image? i.e. `<img style="width:100%;max-width:300px !important;height:auto;"...`

Comment: It seems it was minified CSS.  I took the exact same CSS, un-minified it and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was minified CSS.  When I took the exact same CSS, un-minified it and put that in the head section, Outlook mobile worked as expected.  Swap back to minified and it broke again.

Comment: This saves my life.